# Cannot retrieve previous page token for Blogger v3 API

Tags: json, blogger

I'm trying to make a simple API request using Google's Blogger API. Specifically, I'd like to get a list of posts for my blog and display 3 results at a time, allowing for paging forwards AND backwards. I'm having troubles getting a "previousPageToken" response back from the API and think I might be doing something wrong as their example they have does include this property when appropriate. [This is the example I'm following](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingPostsForABlog) and their proposed output.  [image]

Below is the same url with the same blog id. The blog has hundreds of posts.

The request (I removed my API key):

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts?key=API-KEY&maxResults=3

The response:

```
 "kind": "blogger#postList",
 "nextPageToken": "CgkIAxiA7Pz3iCsQ0b2SAQ",
 "items": [...
```

Okay fine that's page 1 so I don't expect a previous page token.

Next page request:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts?key=API-KEY&maxResults=3&pageToken=CgkIAxiA7Pz3iCsQ0b2SAQ

```
 "kind": "blogger#postList",
 "nextPageToken": "CgkIAxiAoM68xyoQ0b2SAQ"
 "items": [...
```

Uh, what? We are on page two but the API didn't return a previous page token.

Am I querying incorrectly or misunderstanding something?

Comment: I noticed a similar issue when testing at my end. Maybe using the public Feeds would be a better idea. Like for example https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOGID/posts/default/?alt=json&max-results=3&start-index=3. The properties that you need to look out for are `openSearch$totalResults` , `openSearch$startIndex` and `openSearch$itemsPerPage`

Comment: Excellent - that should give me enough to enumerate backwards and forwards. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thank you.

Comment: For future visitors, better workaround would be to store the `nextPageToken`s (for example in `useState` for react apps) and use them as `prevPageToken`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jon Skeet on the .NET client library on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1327) he identified this as a documentation bug. The "PreviousPageToken" property no longer exists in v3 of the Blogger API - but did exist in V2. I was able to work around the now-missing property by storing the publish dates of the starting and ending posts from my result set and using those to go forward and backward using the startDate and endDate API parameters.